# Can Winelib link a DLL directly to the ELF executable?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, dll, wine

There is a DLL (no source code, but no fancy stuff expected inside, hopefully). Going to write a Linux application to use it. So, GNU all the way: native Linux gcc/gdb/ELF, etc.

I've found here on SO some solutions: with WineLib it's possible to write a code that have access to the win32 `LoadLibrary` function, and that code still compiles into ELF binary. A bit of API forwarding and here is a *.so file that calls `LoadLibrary` on the dll and exposes its functions.

Is it correct?

Is it possible to automate it? Is there an example with `winedump` and `winegcc` that are probably the tools for this job?

Comment: `winebuild` is designed to do just that. `winegcc` has a lot of code dedicated to figuring out which  argument points to a so and which points to a dll. After sorting it just tells `winebuild` to make a big stub.

Comment: My wine install (on WSL) will probably take half an hour more, but https://wine-devel.winehq.narkive.com/8KELPuhs/linking-a-winelib-application-with-a-windows-dll seems to have figured out the old way. You `winedump` a libfoo.def file for foo.dll, and just `-lfoo` on winegcc. `winegcc` source seems to show that there's no newer way.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds all perfectly reasonable. The DLL format is properly ancient, and not excessively complex (it had to work on the original 8086 CPU, and it got *simpler* with 32 bits Windows). Code is just that, x86 instructions, and data may be even more boring.

However, it sounds also very specialized, which probably explains why I've never heard of an actual implementation of this idea.